# Display currently running applications that would normally be seeing in the taskbar

Tags: wingpanel, programming

I have many small programs that display their instance inside the taskboard of gnome like `teamviewer` or `insync`.

Normally they are shown in the taskbar.

So now I have noway of opening these programs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try killall for the individual programs before trying to run them. That must do the job.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Indeed, I could kill them. But the point for me is that I shouldn't have to kill them all on system Startup. I'd rather just be able to see the running applications. :D

Comment: That is a design flaw, I believe. Hope it does not bother you too much.

Comment: Ye, sadly it means I cannot use these problems. I've not found a way around this situation yet, so i think I'll need to switch back to Mint, which is a shame.